# linux Find command not working through crontab

Tags: linux

I am using the command given below to delete the 2 days old data from the folder. The command works fine when I run this through directly terminal but not working through crontab entry.

```
find /backup/DWHPROD/ -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Crontab Entry :

```
30 16 * * * find /backup/DWHPROD/ -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: can you try adding ~/.bash_profile in front of your command like * * * * * . ~/.bash_profile; find /backup/DWHPROD/ -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \; . It is possible that PATH is not set while running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the which command, it finds the location of the executable file and displays it. Please run the command in your terminal:

```
which find
```

Here we are finding it located at `/usr/bin/find`.

Try adding that in your crontab script

```
30 16 * * * /usr/bin/find /backup/DWHPROD/ -type f -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```